# How can I execute commands while Gulp.js is watching files?

Tags: macos, terminal, gulp, gulp-watch

I know that there are gulp plugins for executing commands within tasks. What I want to do is run Gulp and while it watching files, I can switch my git branch without having to open a new terminal tab, execute the command there, and then switch back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command to run *Gulp* in background mode and redirect all output to `/dev/null`

```
nohup gulp > /dev/null &
```